# Removing localhost as allowed CORS origin only for the production environment?

Tags: java, spring-boot

For my Spring Boot Backend I have to add "http://localhost:4200/" to the allowed CORS origins, so that I can test my frontend aginst the deployed server.
I used to remove localhost from the allowed / whitelisted CORS list before deploying my backend on the production environment. However, this is getting a bit annoying, is there a way to toggle code lines on / off in Spring Boot?

My code for the CORS Settings in :

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Bean
  CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(
        ... some other domains,
        "http://localhost:4200/"
    ));
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }
}
```

So I would look for something like:

```
if (environment.name == 'PROD') {
   configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(
        ... some other domains
    ));
else {
   configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList(
        ... some other domains,
        "http://localhost:4200/"
    ));
}
```

where I can replace a local environment file with a prod environment file during the build command, as you would do in React or Angular.

Comment: Don't do this code. Add allowed domains in application.profile.properties

Answer (score 0):

Use annotation likes this

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@GetMapping("/greeting")
public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== get greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
}
```

see https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/#controller-method-cors-configuration